# PHP Composer lock file interoperability between Windows and Linux

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it safe to create a composer lock file in Windows, use that lock file in a server that runs on Linux (Centos 6.8 to be exact) and expect the same installed packages/functionality as long as PHP versions match between the 2? My current dev environment actually relies on Docker with containers that mimic our production server but I run into an issue if I use Composer on it. While it works fine, trying to get Laravel Dusk (an automated browser testing framework by the Laravel developers) to work headless in an acceptable manner on my Centos setup is a frustrating task. But that's a problem better fit as a separate question.

In comparison, it works fine on my host/Windows but I would have to run Composer there instead to generate the necessary bin .bat files since Dusk needs to make calls to /path/to/composer/bin/phpunit.bat on a Windows environment.

The following is how my composer file looks like (basically close to stock with some extra libraries)

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3",
        "imagine/imagine": "~0.5.0",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.7.0",
        "laravel/dusk": "^1.0",
        "laravel/browser-kit-testing": "^1.0",
        "santigarcor/laratrust": "3.0.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^2.0",
        "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
        "deployer/deployer": "^4.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/BrowserKitTest.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to see your `composer.json` file

Comment: Updated question with the contents of my composer file